# "make homepage" button/option is missing in SharePoint

Tags: untagged

So here's a frustrating problem. I want to make a different sharepoint page the "home" page for my team, but there's no "make homepage" option in the top menu or the right-click context menu. I've tried:

- confirming it's not in an edit state needing republishing
- checking it out and back in
- looking for different views and menu options that might not be readily apparent
- searching online for similar problems (totally fruitless - most of the results are just explaining how to do it when the button isn't missing).

Now what? Does anyone know how to find my missing option?

Comment: Check if these relate to your problem : [link1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-online-not-able-to-set-a-default/13aacfb4-6b57-485b-ab60-1d09dba2d6c9) and [link2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/edit-button-has-disappeared-from-subsite-home-page/f7637cad-ae77-4ea8-ad59-d4ed677660ad).

Answer (score 1):

I turns out I wasn't an owner of the page and only owners can use that function.